# How do wrap these groups of li elements in ul containers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Goal:**

First wrap the elements before the first empty div in a set of `ul` containers and then do the same for the elements that are between empty `li`s.

The empty element can be included in the container or removed.

**Question:**

How do I wrap these sets of elements in a set of `ul` containers if I can't target the class?

**Problem:**

1)  The only variable I can use is the empty `li` because there will be a different amount of elements in each container.

2) The html doesn't end with an empty `li`.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="body">
<fieldset>
<ol>

<li>
    <h6>Customer Details</h6>
</li>
<li>
    <h6>Customer Details</h6>
</li>
```

wrap elements above

```
<li>&nbsp;</li>
```

wrap elements below until the next empty `li`

```
<li>
    <h6>Customer Details</h6>
</li>
<li>
    <h6>Customer Details</h6>
</li>
<li>
    <h6>Customer Details</h6>
</li>
<li>&nbsp;</li>
```

wrap elements below until the next empty `li`

```
<li>
    <h6>Customer Details</h6>
</li>
<li>
    <h6>Customer Details</h6>
</li>
<li>
    <h6>Customer Details</h6>
</li>
<li>
    <h6>Customer Details</h6>
</li>

</ol>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: `ul > div` is not valid HTML. Also what is empty div? `<div></div>`, `<div>\r\n</div>`, `<div class="empty"></div>`...?

Comment: why don't you try prepend and append jquery methods for your problem. for this take a reference of w3schools like sites.

Comment: I now how to do basic .wrap and .wrapAll functions, my problem is that i dont now how to target the list and wrap all elements that are between empty li elements in a ul container - i cant use class or count the numbers if the order since it changes and doesn't have a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is completely untested as I am on my phone, but I'm happy to update if there's syntax errors. It relies on you being able to select/identify the parent to the HTML you have provided (assuming you have failed to add the final empty divider referred to in a comment above).

```
// Get the known parent to this mess of li elements
var knownParent = $(...);
// Give the empty li elements an identifying class
knownParent.find("li").filter(function(){ return $(this).html().match(/&nbsp;/) !== null; }).addClass("_liDivider");
// Wrap everything between the dividers with a ul element
$.each(
  $("._liDivider:not(:last-child)"), function() {
      $(this)
        .nextUntil("._liDivider")
        .wrap("<ul></ul>");
    }
);
// Now deal with the orphaned li elements before the first divider
knownParent.find("li:first-of-type").nextUntil("._liDivider").wrap("<ul></ul>");
```

Comment: I think this will wrap each non empty `li` with the `ul` tag. Haven't tried this but a similar solution.

Comment: It shouldn't. From the manual: "Get all following siblings of each element up to but not including the element matched by the selector, DOM node, or jQuery object passed"

Comment: Hi and thanks for the suggestion. For some reason it wont give the li element its class. They are wrapped in a ol container wich is wrapped in a <fieldset> container - and then wrapped in a .body class

Comment: As I said, completely untested. I have now changed the selector for the dividers so that it uses a filter, which I've read is the best way to select &nbsp; elements

Comment: Now it works a little better - the last part gives me Unexpected identifier. the first two parts works. it doesn not wrap the first li elements above. I also changed wrap to wrapAll to make it wrap all in in between the emtyp div in a single ul container.

Comment: Sorry, my idiot mobile put a space in knownParent. Try now :)

Comment: Now it works - amazing. Very interesting, thanks a lot!